# Postgresql compound index for spatial + time parameters

Tags: postgresql, indexing, postgis

We have a table that has millions of rows with PostGIS geometries in them. The query we want to perform is: what are the most recent entries that fall within a bounding geometry? The problem with this query is that we'll often have a large number of items that match the bounding box (which has around 5km in radius), and Postgres will then have to re-check all the returned items inside the bounding box to get their timestamp, then sort and return the latest N.

It feels like what we need is a (compound?) index that takes into account both the GIST spatial index and the timestamp as well. Is such a thing possible? I've tried several combinations in the CREATE INDEX step and nothing's worked so far.

Comment: Is this accepted answer working for you? It looks like second index on timestamp won't help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'd rather make two indexes, one spatial and the second on the timestamp column. PostgreSQL can combine indexes pretty nice and it doesn't need to 're-check' found rows. It could use indexes to get the rows within the geometry and sort them using the other index.

Comment: how can I know if the indexes are properly used in combination? I don't believe this answer.

Comment: Use explain (or explain analyze) to check the query plan. There is nothing you should believe if you can check it.

Comment: thank you! I'll try it and vote up if it works well. When I said "I don't believe" is because MySQL does not work well if I create separated indexes, specially with geoindex together.

Comment: This is Postgres, not MySQL. Many things work here differently :) And Postgres can combine many different indexes without any problem.

Comment: But I have to create a compound index geo+other or if I do it separately it should works? Thanks again! :)

Comment: in my case, postgresql does not use the second index on the timestamp column, but does a disk-sort instead.